# In a batch process, is there a way to close only a document in Acrobat Reader DC?

Tags: windows, batch-processing, acrobat

In a batch process, on Windows 10, I'm using this command:

```
taskkill /IM AcroRd32.exe & exit /b 0
```

to close Acrobat Reader DC.

It works perfectly for my needs, but sometimes I want to close only one of the documents open in Acrobat Reader at the moment of the run, not all (as it happens now, obviously, closing Acrobat).

Is there a way to do it?